# How to add views dynamically to Horizontal Scroll View?

Tags: android, adapter, horizontalscrollview

I need to have horizontal scroll view, but the number of views in it is not static. Can one dynamically add views to a horizontal scroll view using adapters, just as we can do in a ListView?

Comment: I do accept the answers if known..Every time i click it, it says, ur reputation is low to accept it.

Comment: And, i made research before posting a question. got few answers, but not efficient enough for my question.